# What does the "eye" control in picture in picture mode do?

Tags: tabletop-simulator

In tabletop simulator there is a "picture in picture" tool.
One of the controls is an "eye" icon, but I have no idea what it actually does.

**Does anyone know what this control does?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest update they have added tooltip text to the control.
This is what it says in both states of the control:

[image]

[image]

So it would appear that it edits the `pip view` to simulate either a `player` or a `spectator` perspective.  (not really sure when that feature would be very helpful, but at least now we know does the control does.)